# Can I use command blocks to /give me an item with a coloured name?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Lots of questions from me today. Here is my command so far:

```
/give @p minecraft:writable_book 1 0 {pages:[""],display:{Name:"Command Book",color:purple}}
```

I want a simple command book but I'd like it to look nice, with a colored name for when I hover over it in my inventory. I have tried and tried and searched the internet, but without third party sources I cant find a way to spawn it with a colored name within a command block. Can anyone help?

Comment: Possile duplicate of [Colored item names in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/201496/colored-item-names-in-minecraft)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use some external world editor capable of editing a block's NBT data. For example, [MCEdit](https://khroki.github.io/MCEdit-Unified/).

Open up the command block's data (method varies by tool; with MCEdit, run the "NBT Edit" filter with the command block selected):

[image: NBT Editor]

Then, in the "Command" string, paste in a section sign (§) followed by a [formatting code](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Formatting_codes) corresponding to the colour you want right before the text you want coloured:

[image: NBT Editor editing a tag]

When you go back into the game, the command in the block should look like this:

[image: Coloured command in a command block]

And give books that look like this:

[image]

Comment: It works! Thank you very much xD I was confused at first as I haven't used MCEdit before.

Comment: I always put an `§r` at the end of the text to reset the formatting. That would un-highlight the `"}}` at the end, which makes it look better.

Comment: @Mystery You can, but it doesn't really matter other than looking at the command; the book it gives will still be the same.

Comment: I know, but its easier to debug when looking at the cmd-block directly instead of using an external editor.