# How do I give items a colored name?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a 1.9 map where it gives a player a sunflower (`double_plant`) with a yellow colored name "Quest Token", and a lore saying "Use this to trade with Quest Villagers". How would I do that? My original commands were:

```
/give @a double_plant 1 0 {display:{Name:"§r§eQuest Token,Lore:"Use this to trade with Quest Villagers"}}
/give @a double_plant 1 0 {display:{Name:"&r&eQuest Token,Lore:"Use this to trade with Quest Villagers"}}
```

Comment: The first command should work, but you'll need to enter them via a 3rd party tool (e.g: [MCEdit](http://www.mcedit-unified.net/)), as Minecraft doesn't support entering the `§` symbol into command blocks.

Comment: Related http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/201496/colored-item-names-in-minecraft

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your quotation marks are unbalanced. You should add a quotation mark after 'Token'

```
/give @a double_plant 1 0 {display:{Name:"§r§eQuest Token",Lore:"Use this to trade with Quest Villagers"}}
```

This will give you the token, but if you try to enter this command into the minecraft chat client, the section symbols will be stripped out, and the coloring won't work.

You'll have to use a third-party tool like [MCEdit](http://www.mcedit.net/) to enter this text into a command block.

Comment: so, specific symbols before a item name colors it, eh? I thought this was only possible through mods

Comment: The section symbol (§) is used by the minecraft rendering engine to control color (and several other text formatting options such as italics or strikethrough) of text. Book an quill is one of the places this is used. However, the symbol cannot be entered from the command block GUI, and instead has to be applied from another source, such as a command- executing sign or 3rd party program.

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to color your items, there's a mod called Text Formatting. It allows the "§" (Section Symbol) to be pasted in Command Blocks and Chat. Additionally it lets you add other symbols not "allowed" in CmdBlocks and Chat, and allows coloring in anvils

http://spacechase0.com/mods/minecraft/text-formatting/