# How to color and remove emphasis on item names?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am currently making a remake of the [Cobalt Shield](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Cobalt_Shield) in Minecraft 1.14.3, but I do not know how to change the custom item name's formatting in-game.

Can someone help me figure out how to color the item name and make font adjustments to it, i.e. make it non-italicized?

I tried to use this command:

```
/give @s minecraft:shield
{
  BlockEntityTag:
  {
    Base:11,
    Patterns:
    [
      {
        Color:9,
        Pattern:"vhr"
      },
      {
        Color:15,
        Pattern:"cs"
      },
      {
        Color:15,
        Pattern:"ms"
      },
      {
        Color:4,
        Pattern:"sc"
      },
      {
        Color:15,
        Pattern:"gru"
      }
    ]
  },
  AttributeModifiers:
  [
    {
      AttributeName:"generic.knockbackResistance",
      Name:"Block",
      Slot:"offhand",
      Amount:100,
      Operation:0,
      UUIDMost:71140,
      UUIDLeast:113080
    }
  ],
  Unbreakable:1b,
  display:
  {
    Name:"{\"text\":\"Cobalt Shield\"}"
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking, but at least could you include what version of Minecraft you're using?

Comment: He wants to know how to color the name "Cobalt Shield", in the display tag of the command. He also wants to know how to make the name non-italicized.

Comment: @Kaleb Unfortunately, I cannot answer it because it has been put on hold, but your display tag should look like this: `display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Cobalt Shield\",\"color\":\"dark_aqua\",\"italic\":\"false\"}"`.

Comment: Additionally, this [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/201496/colored-item-names-in-minecraft?rq=1) has more information plus a link you can peruse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your display tag should look like this:

```
  display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Cobalt Shield\",\"color\":\"dark_aqua\",\"italic\":\"false\"}"
```

Because you are modifying the color and font style of the name, it goes in the `Name` tag. What you are doing, essentially, is this: `{"text":"Cobalt Shield","color":"dark_aqua","italic":"false"}`, but because this is a String (series of characters) containing JSON being passed into Minecraft you need to enclose the whole thing in quotes and you need to escape the quotes containing the JSON pairs, meaning put a backslash `\` before each of them, which is why it looks so complicated.