# How do I execute for a player wearing armor with a colored name

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am working on a command block contraption on my server that involves armor giving you certain potion effects.

`/execute if entity @p[nbt={Inventory[{Slot:100b,id:"minecraft:leather_boots",tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Frog Boots\"}"}}}]}] run effect give @s jump_boost 1 1 true`

However, it only works if the boots are named in an anvil. How would I write the command if I wanted to test if the player was wearing boots named "Frog Boots" in bold and green text?

Answer (score 3):

The NBT syntax for testing for an item with a certain name is exactly the same as the NBT syntax for giving a player an item with that name. Thus, if you give a player boots using the command:

```
/give <player> leather_boots{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Frog Boots\",\"color\":\"green\",\"bold\":true}"}}
```

(per my answer to [Colored item names in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/201496/colored-item-names-in-minecraft)), you check if the player is wearing those boots using the command:

```
/execute if entity @p[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:100b,id:"minecraft:leather_boots",tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Frog Boots\",\"color\":\"green\",\"bold\":true}"}}}]}] run ...
```

You can figure out the exact NBT name of an item by selecting it, and running the command:

```
/data get entity @s SelectedItem.tag.display.Name
```

Comment: I don’t know how to use the items data, and use it in an execute command. I’ve tried /execute if entity @p[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:100b,id:"minecraft:leather_boots",tag:{Display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Frog Boots\",\"color\":\"green\",\"bold\":true}"}}}]}] but it doesn’t seem to work

Comment: Try using the second command listed by @pppery but with `@a` instead of `@p` because `@p` only checks the nearest player relative to the command block (or the player typing the command) also `@a` is compatible with more than one player using the item.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Answer from the OP, posted in the question body:</sub>

---

I found out you can test if the player is wearing dyed armor, so I’m doing that instead.