# How to detect color-named armor? (1.15.2)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to detect a golden armor that has a yellow name, prot 26 and fire prot 20. 
`/give @s minecraft:golden_helmet{Unbreakable:1,Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:protection",lvl:26},{id:"minecraft:fire_protection",lvl:20}],HideFlags:1} 1`
[image: How it looks]
Edit: I don't know if it matters, but i used /itemrename &eShinee Glowstone Chestplate. I tried using `/data get entity @s SelectedItem.tag.display.Name`.[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I execute for a player wearing armor with a colored name](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/369053/how-do-i-execute-for-a-player-wearing-armor-with-a-colored-name)

Comment: Sadly, no. I tried everything but it still said "Test Failed". I even tried giving the item, and it still said "Test Failed".

Comment: @Zzz Which exact commands did you use to give yourself the armour and to check for the armour?